# Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id **********; first error: TEMPLATE_NOT_FOUND,

Tags: apex, visualforce, email, email-template

I am facing the below error

Exception Details: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id *************; first error: TEMPLATE_NOT_FOUND, The record couldn't be saved because it triggered an email alert that failed. Please contact salesforce.com Customer Support.: []

The scenario is that we have a WF Rule on the Invoice object which fires the Email Alert after Registration. The Invoice Template is a VF Page.
I researched for it and most of the folks suggest checking the permissions of the fields referenced in the Email template. I do that but still, I am getting the same error.

It's the second time I am facing this particular issue. The first time it was resolved by giving permission to a new field added on the Invoice object. But this time it happens suddenly without adding any new field.

Please suggest a way to resolve it
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This error may be related to the Spring '21 release that has been rolling out.  They have changed the permissions granted to a Site Guest user.  You may find that your email template, the one 'not found', may be trying to access a formula field on another object that the site user does not have permissions to.

I had tried granting permissions to the object and the field the formula field referenced, but this did not resolve the issue for me.  For reference, I also tried creating a custom controller that would access the fields without the sharing permissions, but that didn't work either.